# How to inject ApplicationContext itself

Tags: java, spring, applicationcontext

I want to inject an `ApplicationContext` itself to a bean.

Something like

```
public void setApplicationContext(ApplicationContect context) {
  this.context = context;
}
```

Is that possible in spring?

Answer (score 142, accepted):

Previous comments are ok, but I usually prefer:

```
@Autowired private ApplicationContext applicationContext;
```

Comment: +1 Btw, do you have any idea about pros cons between injecting applicationContext by directly @Autowired or implementing ApplicationContextAware interface? Thanks.

Comment: @Bariscan: I think there are no pros and cons. But I prefer this because @ Autowired is what I use for injecting all properties, so whay to do it differently just beacuse is an ApplicationContext?

Comment: Can you provide a more detailed example of @Autowired (I'm a big fan) Application context? It is always null for me. Any extra interfaces needed? Thx.

Comment: Is @Autowired injecting other properties in same bean? The exact same code works for me in Spring 3.1.1.

Comment: While I agree that `@Autowired` is nice; The difference between using `@Autowired` and ApplicationContextAware can be astonishing when circular references are involved. It turned out that simply removing `@Autowired` solved the issue I described in [circular-dependency-in-spring](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3485347/circular-dependency-in-spring/17111644#17111644)

Answer (score 44):

Easy, using the `ApplicationContextAware` interface.

```
public class A implements ApplicationContextAware {
  private ApplicationContext context;

  public void setApplicationContext(ApplicationContext context) {
      this.context = context;
  }
}
```

Then in your actual applicationContext you only need to reference your bean.

```
<bean id="a" class="com.company.A" />
```

Answer (score 13):

Yes, just implement the [ApplicationContextAware](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/context/ApplicationContextAware.html) -interface.

Answer (score 3):

I saw some comments above about @Autowired not working still. The following may help.

This will not work:

```
@Route(value = "content", layout = MainView.class)
public class MyLayout extends VerticalLayout implements RouterLayout {

  @Autowired private ApplicationContext context;

   public MyLayout() {
    comps.add(context.getBean(MyComponentA.class)); // context always null :(
}
```

You must do this:

```
 @Autowired
  public MyLayout(ApplicationContext context) {
    comps.add(context.getBean(MyComponentA.class)); //context is set :)
}
```

or this:

```
@PostConstruct
    private void init() {
    comps.add(context.getBean(MyComponentA.class)); // context is set :)
}
```

Also note that Upload is another component that must be set within the scope of @PostConstruct. This was a nightmare for me to figure out. Hope this helps!

I almost forgot to mention that the @Scope annotation may be necessary for your Bean, as seen below. This was the case when using Upload within a Bean because  the UI is not instantiate/attached prior to the Bean being created and will cause a Null Reference Exception to be thrown. It won't do so when using @Route, but will when using @Component - so the latter is not an option and if @Route is not viable, then I would recommend using @Configuration class to create the bean with the prototype scope.

```
@Configuration
public class MyConfig {
  @Bean
  @Scope(value = ConfigurableBeanFactory.SCOPE_PROTOTYPE, proxyMode = ScopedProxyMode.TARGET_CLASS)
  public MyComponentA getMyBean() {
    return new MyComponentA();
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Special solution: get Spring beans from any (non Spring) classes

```
@Component
public class SpringContext {
    private static ApplicationContext applicationContext;

    @Autowired
    private void setApplicationContext(ApplicationContext ctx) {
        applicationContext = ctx;
    }

    public static <T> T getBean(Class<T> componentClass) {
        return applicationContext.getBean(componentClass);
    }
}
```