# How to inject ApplicationContext in JAX-RS

Tags: java, spring, web-services, jax-rs

I am writing a web service using Spring and JAX-RS, and I'm kinda confused with the following

Here's my service exmaple

```
@Path("/users")
public class UserService {

    @GET
    @Path("{id}")
    @Produces("application/xml")
    public User getById(@PathParam("id") int id) {
        ApplicationContext context = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("beans.xml");
        UserDAO userDAO = (UserDAO) context.getBean("userDao");
        return userDAO.getById(id);
    }

}
```

And here's my beans.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
       xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd">

    <!-- Initialization for data source -->
    <bean id="dataSource" class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource">
        <property name="driverClassName" value="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"/>
        <property name="url" value="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/hospital-system"/>
        <property name="username" value="root"/>
        <property name="password" value="root"/>
    </bean>

    <bean id="userDao" class="dao.UserDAO">
        <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource"/>
    </bean>

</beans>
```

I wonder if this is the right technique to load Application context each time the resource get's called, and if no, how should I change it?

Comment: What JAX-RS implementation and version are you using?

Comment: the jax-rs is the following

<groupId>javax.ws.rs</groupId>
<artifactId>jsr311-api</artifactId>
<version>1.1.1</version>

Comment: and the jersey server 1.2

Comment: See [this](http://www.mkyong.com/webservices/jax-rs/jersey-spring-integration-example/). You should be able to just @Autowired the service (without needing the context). Change the version of the dependency to 1.2 as needed (as the tutorial uses a newer version. I think it should still work with older version)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Creating the application factory instance everytime when a web service call is made to this method is definitely, not a good approach ,

as this method might get called maybe say 100 times, we do not want to have a over head of creating this context 100 times as nothing is going to change in it.

you may implement the  `ApplicationContextAware` interface

- [How to inject ApplicationContext itself](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4914012/how-to-inject-applicationcontext-itself)

and you can do

`ApplicationContext context = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("beans.xml");`

at some other place , maybe when your application starts up.

hope this helps!

Good luck!

Comment: will it also share the same context between other services?

Comment: Yes , if its defined when your application starts up and you only autowire it in the places you use it, the context will be shared by services in entire application

Comment: @Autowired only works in objects created by spring. By default, Jersey does not use Spring to create resource objects.

Answer (score 3):

The Jersey reference manual [describes](https://jersey.java.net/documentation/latest/user-guide.html#spring) how to integrate with Spring in detail:

> Jersey provides an extension to support Spring DI. This enables Jersey to use Spring beans as JAX-RS components (e.g. resources and providers) and also allows Spring to inject into Jersey managed components.
>
> The Spring extension module configuration is based on annotations. Spring beans are injected and JAX-RS classes are made Spring managed using annotations. Injected Spring beans can have further dependencies injected using Spring XML configuration. Spring singleton and request scopes are supported.
>
> To enable JAX-RS resources to work Spring functionality that requires proxying, such as Spring transaction management (with @Transactional), Spring Security and aspect oriented programming (such as @Aspect), the resources must themselves be managed by Spring, by annotating with @Component, @Service, @Controller or @Repository:
>
> ```
> import javax.ws.rs.GET;
> import javax.ws.rs.Path;
> import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;
>
> @Component
> @Path("/")
> public class SomeResource {
>
>     @Transactional
>     @GET
>     public void updateResource() {
>         // ...
>     }
> }
> ```
>
> Limitations:
>
> - Spring beans can't be injected directly into JAX-RS classes by using Spring XML configuration
>
> **Dependencies**
>
> If you want to use Jersey Spring DI support you will need to add the jersey-spring3 module into the list of your dependencies:
>
> ```
> <dependency>
>     <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.ext</groupId>
>     <artifactId>jersey-spring3</artifactId>
>     <version>2.18</version>
> </dependency>
> ```
>
> The above module adds transitive dependencies on Spring modules. See jersey-spring3 module dependencies for more details about list and scope of dependencies. Please note the module depends on The Spring/HK2 Bridge that is used to inject Spring services into HK2 services or inject HK2 services into Spring services.
>
> To see an example of Spring DI support in Jersey refer to the [Spring DI Example](https://github.com/jersey/jersey/tree/2.18/examples/helloworld-spring-webapp).

Comment: The jersey link seems to be obsolete. I found this one working : https://jersey.github.io/documentation/latest/spring.html