# Get access to spring context from JUnit test

Tags: spring, testing, junit

I try to run test for spring framework. I use only the xml context. In test (JUnit) class I specify

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@ContextConfiguration(locations = {"springContext.xml"})
public class MyTest extends TestCase {
    @Test
    public void test() {

    }
}
```

but I don't know how to get access to the spring context in the `@Test` method? I don't can use of `@Autowired` annotation, because I don't use annotation driven context

Comment: I'm fairly sure you can still autowire even if your beans are only in xml, with @Autowired. It will autowire by type and name.

Comment: @gowayward, it is not necessary to specify the `<context:annotation-config />`  in xml config?

Comment: Autowired has nothing to do with annotation driven context.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The test class is like a regular bean. So far you can use both of those in your test class:

- autowire ApplicationContext
- implement ContextAware interface

See [How to inject ApplicationContext itself](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4914012/how-to-inject-applicationcontext-itself)