# Is it possible for spring to create two beans simultaneously?

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, illegalstateexception, method-invocation

I'm facing a problem where spring tries to call getter of a bean through reflection and then it throws illegal state exception saying bean is ' currently under creation' . Shouldn't spring know that it can't call a bean's method unless its instantiated ? All dependency injections are done by Spring in this case. Is it possible that two beans share ClassABC  and if they are being create simultaneously they might throw this exception ?

log trace:

```
java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
        at org.springframework.beans.BeanWrapperImpl.getPropertyValue(BeanWrapperImpl.java:845)
        at org.springframework.beans.BeanWrapperImpl.getNestedBeanWrapper(BeanWrapperImpl.java:576)
        at org.springframework.beans.BeanWrapperImpl.getBeanWrapperForPropertyPath(BeanWrapperImpl.java:553)
        at org.springframework.beans.BeanWrapperImpl.getBeanWrapperForPropertyPath(BeanWrapperImpl.java:554)
        at org.springframework.beans.BeanWrapperImpl.setPropertyValue(BeanWrapperImpl.java:914)
        at org.springframework.beans.AbstractPropertyAccessor.setPropertyValues(AbstractPropertyAccessor.java:76)
        at org.springframework.beans.AbstractPropertyAccessor.setPropertyValues(AbstractPropertyAccessor.java:58)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.applyPropertyValues(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1393)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1118)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:517)
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException: null
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
        at org.springframework.beans.BeanWrapperImpl.getPropertyValue(BeanWrapperImpl.java:761)
        at org.springframework.beans.BeanWrapperImpl.getNestedBeanWrapper(BeanWrapperImpl.java:576)
        at org.springframework.beans.BeanWrapperImpl.getBeanWrapperForPropertyPath(BeanWrapperImpl.java:553)
        at org.springframework.beans.BeanWrapperImpl.getBeanWrapperForPropertyPath(BeanWrapperImpl.java:554)
        at org.springframework.beans.BeanWrapperImpl.setPropertyValue(BeanWrapperImpl.java:914)
        at org.springframework.beans.AbstractPropertyAccessor.setPropertyValues(AbstractPropertyAccessor.java:76)
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Flow [ClassABC (flow-class=com.path.to.package.ClassABC)] is currently in creation!
```

Comment: You may want to check this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3485347/circular-dependency-in-spring

Comment: Post your beans with their config to have a clear picture on whats happening

Comment: Kindly post ur code. Then only We can able to see where is the prob?

Comment: provide contents of your beanConfiguration.xml File . We can suggest then something