# Failed to start project sometimes,report an error : unresolvable circular reference

Tags: spring

We failed to start project sometimes, of course launched successfully most of the time. Error reported during failure:

```
[AbstractApplicationContext.java] refresh : 487 -- Exception encountered during context initialization - cancelling refresh attempt 
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCurrentlyInCreationException: 
Error creating bean with name 'ITsysDesktopConfig': 
Requested bean is currently in creation: 
Is there an unresolvable circular reference?
```

I am  sure there is no circular reference.

Spring version 4.1.1.RELEASE is used, and I use Spring XML file, not annotation in project

When I was using computer with higher configuration，there is less chance of error happening.

Answer (score -1):

The problem could be with

`@ComponentScan(basePackages = "com.my.app")`

Try to change

`@ComponentScan(basePackages = "com.my.app")`

to

`@ComponentScan(basePackages = {"com.my.app.service", "com.my.app.config", "com.my.app"})`

I think this is a Spring issue with beans loader...

Reference:

1. https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/issues/6045
2. https://jira.spring.io/browse/SPR-14307
3. [Why does Spring get circular dependency issues on one machine and not another?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29347723/why-does-spring-get-circular-dependency-issues-on-one-machine-and-not-another)
4. https://www.logicbig.com/tutorials/spring-framework/spring-core/circular-dependencies.html

Comment: I reduce the interfaces in DAO, all is OK but I still  have no idea why