# Spring bean stackoverflow error

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, circular-dependency

Suppose I have two classes

Class A

Class B

Now,
Class A has dependency on Class B and Class B has dependency on class B.

Looks like

```
class A {
 private B b;
    public A(B b) {
    this.b = b;
    } 
}

class B {
 private A a;
    public B(A a) {
    this.a = a;
    }
}
```

The bean configuration for the same will be

```
@Bean 
public A getA() {
return new A(getB());
}

@Bean 
public B getB() {
return new B(getA());
}
```

This code results in a deadlock situation as one depeneds on the other. How to instantiate Beans in such case?

Comment: check out this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3485347/circular-dependency-in-spring

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Circular dependency in spring](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3485347/circular-dependency-in-spring)

Answer (score 1):

Try using setter based dependency injection. Topic had also been discussed at [Circular dependency in spring](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3485347/circular-dependency-in-spring)

Answer (score 1):

Other option is to use **@PostConstruct** annotation. In the answer proposed by *Plog* ypu have a problem that initialization of A is done in init method of B. With postConstruct, you can have a dedicated method *resolveCircularDependencies*.

Its just a cosmetic change, but makes it explicit why the wiring is done this way (which comes handy, when you forget about the existence of the cycle, or other programmer encounters the code).

```
@Bean 
public A getA(){
    return new A();
}

@Bean 
public B getB(){
    return new B();
}

@PostConstruct
public void resolveCircularDependencies() {
    getB().setA(getA());
    getA().setB(getB());
}
```