# calling a method from a different class in springBoot

Tags: java, spring

i want to call a method which is containing applicationContext which works fine when run independently but when i try calling it from a different class `appContext.getBean(DataSource.class)` returns null.

```
public class Action {

private static Logger log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(Action.class);

@Autowired
MessageConfigProperties messageProperties;

@Autowired
AutomatorApp automatorApp;

@Autowired
Apps gapps;

@Autowired
Deploy d;

@Autowired
Deploy depstatusChk;

@Autowired
private ApplicationContext appContext;

@Autowired
CreateSaltFileService createSaltFile;

@Autowired
DeployFactory depFactory;

@Autowired
IMoveAppsService moveAppsService;

@Autowired
IUserEnvironmentService userEnvService;

@Autowired
IEnvironmentService envService;

@Autowired
Session session;

private Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(Action.class);
private ServletContext context;

@Context
public void setServletContext(ServletContext context) {
    System.out.println("servlet context set here");
    this.context = context;
}

@POST
@Path("/register/")
@Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
@RequiresRoles("admin")
@RequiresPermissions("automator:register")
public Session register(Session credentials, @BeanParam Session springContext) throws AppException {
    System.out.println("into action class");
    System.out.println("-->>>" +appContext.getBean(DataSource.class));
    appContext.getBean(DataSource.class);
    logger.info(messageProperties.getGreetings());
    // logger.trace("Inside Session");
    System.out.println("Inside Session");
    credentials.setDatasource(springContext.getDatasource());
```

when this Action method is called from

this method agentGroup in different class

```
@POST
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
@ApiOperation(value = "Get List of agent group", response = 
AgentGroup.class, responseContainer = "List")
public ArrayList<AgentGroup> agentGroup(Session credentials, @BeanParam Session springContext) throws AppException, ConfigException, InterruptedException {

    Session r=objA.register(credentials, springContext);
    int sessionId=r.getSessionId();
}
```

Comment: How is objA created?

Comment: Simply like-> Action objA = new Action( );

Comment: In that case, Spring couldn't do any autowiring so all the autowired variables are null. Your code is very strange. Creating rest endpoint via `new` and calling it from another endpoint doesn't make a lot of sense.

Answer (score 1):

You `@Autowire  ApplicationContext appContext` just to get datasource (`appContext.getBean(DataSource.class)`).

Why do not `@Autowire DataSource datasource` directly?
It will make make business logic of your `Action` class independend from Spring.

If you really want to access `ApplicationContext` you may try another approach

make `Action implements ApplicationContextAware`

private ApplicationContext ctx;

```
  @Override
    public void setApplicationContext(ApplicationContext applicationContext)
            throws BeansException {
        ctx = applicationContext;
    }
```

See [Circular dependency in Spring](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3485347/circular-dependency-in-spring/17111644#17111644) for details.

edit:
your `Action` class has no annotation. no `org.springframework.web.bind.annotation. RestController`, no `@Component` or `@Service`. are you sure it is managed by Spring? if it is just created using `new` then Autowire will not work and fields will be null.

Comment: but, now i get null pointer on this line-> 
  GenesysConnectionManager manager = (GenesysConnectionManager) context.getAttribute("GenesysConnectionManager");

Comment: private ServletContext context;

 public void setServletContext(ServletContext context) {
  System.out.println("servlet context set here");
  this.context = context;
 }
 public Session register(Session credentials, @BeanParam Session springContext) throws AppException {
  credentials.setDatasource(springContext.getDatasource());
GenesysConnectionManager manager = (GenesysConnectionManager) context.getAttribute("GenesysConnectionManager");