# Spring Boot Circular Dependency With Interfaces

Tags: java, spring-boot, dependency-injection, circular-dependency

I noticed that I made a circular dependency injection. The weird thing is I did not get any errors at runtime. But when I'm debugging the code I see that there is an infinite injection.

Let me quote interfaces and their implementations.

```
public interface AService {
    //methods here
}
```

..

```
public interface BService {
    //methods here
}
```

..

```
@Service
class AServiceImpl implements AService {

    @Autowired
    private BService bService; 
}
```

..

```
@Service
class BServiceImpl implements BService {

    @Autowired
    private XService xService;
}
```

..

```
@Service
class XService {

 @Autowired
 private AService aService;
}
```

As you see above; `AService -> BService -> XService -> AService`

I did not get any circular dependency exception during run time. But when I put watchpoint on AService in XService I see that there is an infinite loop between above flow.

When I see that I categorized this as a bad design. With using `@Lazy`  annotation it's fixed but anyway I did not understand how I don't get circular dependency injection exception. Is it because I'm using interfaces and hiding implementations?

Thank you.

Comment: Try injecting `XService` into a very separate Class

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3485347/circular-dependency-in-spring
and https://www.baeldung.com/circular-dependencies-in-spring

Comment: "The beans are instantiated first, then injected into each other." @Richard Fearn
So I did nothing neither constructor injection nor setter method. Just autowired the circular dependencies and Spring resolved it? Want to get your attention again that I injected dependencies as classical way with Autowired and somehow Spring resolved circular injection; however I can see during debugging that dependencies are going infinite but there is no any exceptions.

Comment: Ok, now I learnt a thing that there is no need for setter method if we autowire dependency field. So I guess with autowired field spring still resolves the circular dependency exception