# How will allowing the flag spring.main.allow-circular-references=true construct the beans?

Tags: spring, spring-boot

There is a piece of Spring Boot code that when we try to launch in the cloud (PCF) it gives Bean creation errors. It says there is a possible circular dependency. (I was astonished to find in the console log, it actually traces out arrows in a circle).
However since it involves Rest Templates and such, I am unclear about how to break the loop.
Someone suggested using this property; however if it allows circular references, then how will the beans ever get constructed - will they be unsatisfied always?

```
spring.main.allow-circular-references=true
```

Comment: Interesting question. I'm currently upgrading a project that apparently ran for years in production like that b/c that detection was only [introduced in 2.6](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/wiki/Spring-Boot-2.6-Release-Notes#circular-references-prohibited-by-default): *„This will restore 2.5’s behaviour and automatically attempt to break the dependency cycle.“*

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Circular dependency in Spring](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3485347/circular-dependency-in-spring)